# How does the Wild Hunt Navigator work exactly?

Tags: gwent

The Wild Hunt Navigator effect is listed as

> **Deploy: Summon** a copy of a different Bronze Wild Hunt **Ally**

[image]

I played a few games with a Monsters deck, but I don't think I understand the restrictions on this particular card. In a few cases where I tried to use it, it simply didn't do anything.

I'm probably misunderstanding some aspects of this ability, so how exactly does this card work? Which cards can I copy and which other conditions must be fulfilled for this card to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works exactly as stated on the card. However, it can be quite confusing when you first read it. Firstly, there are exactly four bronze Wild Hunt cards:

- Wild hunt Hound
- Wild hunt Rider
- Wild hunt warrior
- The Wild Hunt Navigator itself

These are the only cards that can be targeted by the Wild Hunt Navigator. That's what the "a bronze Wild Hunt ally" means. It has to be on your side of the board, and it has to be one of these four cards.

The "summon" part means that, if you have at least another copy of the targeted card in your deck, you can take one of the available copies out of your deck and put it on the battlefield.

TL; DR: To properly use this ability, you must have a copy of one of the four cards above on your side of the battlefield, and another one in your deck.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's quite straight forward, if you have a card on the field and a copy of it in your deck (must be bronze and have the wild hunt subtype) you can summon it. maybe you'll find more informations on this [reddit](https://www.google.fr/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/gwent/comments/6d3k19/how_does_wild_hunt_navigator_work/)